# Structs fields assignment in C

Tags: c, struct

I have a MyLinkedList.h file with this lines:

```
typedef struct _MyLinkedList *MyLinkedListP;
```

And in my .c file, I try this and it won't work.

```
#include "MyLinkedList.h"

typedef struct _Node
{
    int _val;
    struct _Node* next;
} Node;

typedef struct _MyLinkedList
{
    int _listSize;
    Node* _firstNode;
};

MyLinkedListP createList()
{
    MyLinkedListP *list = (MyLinkedListP*)malloc(sizeof(MyLinkedListP));
    list._listSize = 0;
    list._firstNode = NULL;
}
```

The ._listSize and ._firstNode is red colored.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two errors:

- `MyLinkedListP` is already a pointer, so `MyLinkedListP *list` is a pointer to a pointer.
- You use `->`, not `.`, to access `struct` fields from a pointer.

Here is how to fix your code:

```
MyLinkedListP list = malloc(sizeof(struct _MyLinkedList));
//           ^       ^
//  No asterisk      No cast          
list->_listSize = 0;
list->_firstNode = NULL;
```

Comment: @chqrlie You are right, I missed the argument of `sizeof`. Thanks!